# Data not get bind with the Binding result in Spring mvc

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, validationerror

I have been facing this problem for the past 2 days. Although I have gone through so many post I did not find a solution for my question.

Actually I was trying to validate my *login* form using Spring validations but even if I had given some wrong inputs it is not showing me any error , it accepts my every input.

**For example, I have used @NotEmpty and @Email annotations for email it even accepts my plain inputs like "user".** *It has to throw the error as "Invalid email format" but this errors are not get bind into my Bindingresult.*

My Controller : ContactController.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.viralpatel.spring3.form.loginform;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import net.viralpatel.spring3.form.Contact;
import net.viralpatel.spring3.form.ContactForm;
import net.viralpatel.spring3.form.loginform;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;@Controller{
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(ModelMap model) {
        loginform ud = new loginform();
         ud.setUser("");
         ud.setEmail("");
        model.addAttribute("lform",ud);
        return "login"; 

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginCheck(@ModelAttribute("lform") @Valid loginform lform, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("lfobj", lform);
            return "success";        

        }
    }
```

My login.jsp file :

```
<form:form action="login.html" commandName="lform">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">User</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="user" /> <form:errors path="user"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Email</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="email" /> <form:errors path="email"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Phone</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="phone" /> <form:errors path="phone"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Blog</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="blog" /> <form:errors path="blog"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

My loginform.java :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

public class loginform{

        @NotEmpty
        private String user;

        @NotEmpty
        @Email
        private String email;        

        @NotEmpty(message = "Phone should not be blank.")
        @Size(min = 10,max = 10)
        private String phone;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Enter your blog URL")
        @URL
        private String blog;
//get & set methods
 }
```

My spring-servlet.xml :

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" /> 

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="props" />
    </bean>
```

*This is my first program in Spring validation so may be I hit low but kindly give any solutions for my issue.*

Comment: do one thing define the regular expression and then check. :)

Comment: which version of spring are you using, and post your spring config

Comment: i am using spring 3.0 and i have also added my spring config file

Comment: Where is your model attribute that u giving for the input of the object of bean

Comment: Sriprem rookie: do you use maven? - then please post the dependencies section, also please post the spring configuration and the import statements of your controller and loginform object.

Comment: i guess spring validation is more easier than the normal regular expressions and it is effective too - @Jaiwo99 .

Comment: i am not using maven.I have imported all the requires jars files under the WEB-INF/lib folder @Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your spring config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

This will enable Bean Validation.

Document: [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html)

Comment: By adding <mvc:annotation-driven/> i got this error - "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl"

Comment: @Sripremrookie Add `hibernate-validator` to your lib, here is the link: http://hibernate.org/validator/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp form tag is missing the http method attribute `method="POST` (without this attribute for form data are submit an http GET, and this is bound to the request handler method):

```
<form:form method="POST" action="login.html" commandName="lform">...
```

Comment: I have tried that one too but still got the same issue .

Comment: I think my Bindingresult didn't get those error values may be some problem with the mapping !

Comment: i dont know what is still wrong in my coding everything seems to be fine ! !